# Настройка SMTP на VPS

Tags: php, smtp, sendmail, windows-server, smtp-server

Взял в аренду VPS на нем стоит вин серв 2003. Нашел мануал как поднять на нем SMTP, поднял, вроде бы. Не уверен так как через аутлук почему то на внешнею почту не отправляет, сам себе отправил норм пришло. Цель всего это счастья отправлять письма с сайта. Нашел вот этот [мануал](http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=email&page=007)  длеаю все по нему, но у меня нет AUTH LOGIN и я уже весь мозг сломал не могу понять что не так делаю. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В мануале прописано smtp.mail.ru у меня ведь это просто ip моего сервера верно?
Прошу помочь ребят!

Comment: Если вам действительно нужна почта на домене, то проще всего взять pdd от яндекса или аналогичное решение от гугла

Comment: @etki у них ограничение на рассылку мне надо около 1000 писем в день отправлять.

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=exchange+504+5.7.4+unrecognized+authentication+type&oq=exchange+504+5.7.4+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0.6925j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: А чтобы спам отправлять по smtp почтовый сервер на самом деле не нужен. Почтовый клиент-спамер сам подключается непосредственно к серверу-жертве.

Comment: @Sergey мне не нужно отправлять спам, у меня на сайте очень активная завязка на email и иногда достигает более 150 писем в час из за этого пользователям не приходят письма для подтверждения например регистрации.